# RabbitMQ - making a demo in the cloud

Tags: cloud, rabbitmq

I've started playing with the excellent RabbitMQ and was thinking of doing something more "real world". Like grabbing a file in any folder, send it through the cloud (everything cool needs to be in the cloud today..) modify it (maybe using Bots) and then return it through mail or xmpp or something.
So, any ideas of free (or trial) clouds out there that would love to host rabbitMQ for me? I ws thinking GAE since I could play with python but I found nothing on how to do that?

Regards

Comment: Cloud is rarely free, but it's not expensive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install Ubuntu on Amazon EC2 and put a rabbitMQ daemon on it.

Comment: would work, but there are no trial accounts on EC2 right? I noticed CloudFoundry seem to work, but not with python